# Are translations to low quality posts acceptable as suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

When going through the "suggested edit" queue, one in particular (now deleted) got me thinking. It was an answer post that was made in a language other than English, but it wasn't an answer to the question: it was a classic "I have the same problem" post.

Per [StackExchange policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange), English is required in all posts. However, it's also quite obvious (especially to frequent reviewers) that there are non-English posts flowing in every once in a while. Most if not all of them are meaningless, in the way of "I have the problem too" or "thank you".

I agree that, if the non-English post is meaningful, we should devote effort to at least a rough translation; however, the example I gave above is the first time I've seen someone trying to translate a post of such low-quality type. Given the fact that such posts will be deleted shortly, are such suggested edits acceptable/encouraged, and are we as reviewers still supposed to approve the edits?

Comment: I find this question interesting, and I'd like to hear what the community thinks about this.

Comment: @DanHulme: although it may not seem relevant to you, but could you please post the screenshot of that  "suggested edit"? It seems that the post has been deleted or something else happened, and we mortals cannot view that edit anymore.

Comment: I feel a little like it would be abusing mod powers to screenshot a deleted post, but I'll edit the text of the question to make it clear.

Comment: @DanHulme Thanks, my bad, didn't think about the fact that we can't view suggested edits on deleted posts when I posted the question.

Comment: I see. No issues, as the edit does the job. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I say, you move beyond the edit and evaluate the worth of the post. If the original post (subjected to translation, when required) holds value to the question (more than just a comment, but may not be a full-fledged answer) and the edit doesn't change the intent of the post, *than accept or improve the edit*.

If the post isn't worth to be an answer at first place or cannot be salvaged or should be a comment, than there is no point in accepting that edit. It would only bring that unworthy post on the front page under Active tab for no good reason. Furthermore, it would award the editor with +2 score. The reputation doesn't matter much here but the encouragement of having such an edit accepted may harm the site in future.

Harmful! How come?

Reviewers are supposed to keep a tab on the quality of the posts on the Stack Exchange sites. Whatever they do, it becomes the norm soon.

- If they begin to accept LQP as worthy to be retained, quality of the site decreases since more LQP is equivalent to more unsatisfied and frustrated users and viewers.
- If they accept low quality edits, they begin to raise an editor **with poor editing skill and judgement**, and that user, after 2k score, would raise  alike editors *through their poor reviewing and unrestricted editing*.
- If they upvote an LQP, others might take that such posts are actually of worth on this site. And users taking LQP as acceptable is never good for any site.

What to do than, other than to reject the edit?

- Just copy-paste the translation, to the extant it is permitted, as a comment on that post so that other users do not indulge in the same editing process.
- Use your judgement towards that LQP accordingly so that other new editors and viewers don't get to see it anymore.
- Ping that editor in a chat and let them know, kindly of course, why such edits should be avoided. It could be a canned response. Alternatively, you could avoid this by having the reason cited when you reject that edit.

Alright, enough opinion for now.

Comment: Well put, got my vote! Even included a well thought "what-to-do". I 100% agree with each word! Special emphasis of what lets make me kudos: the part of "transferring content worth a comment" into a comment, so it's not lost entirely. Thumbs up!

Comment: Thank you Izzy. :-)

Comment: Maybe this is only shown to users with the VTD privilege, but I think one of the possible actions when reviewing edits is to delete the post.